# laravel при использование SoftDeletes создает запись 2 раза

Tags: php, laravel

Изучаю Laravel, всё бы ничего, я прописал роутинг, при переходе на страницу в базе данных создаются 4 записи, но когда в модели я подключаю SoftDeletes, то при php artisan migrate:fresh и попытке снова создать записи путем перехода по странице у меня записи создаются дважды, тоесть вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения], с чем это связано, как пофиксить? В гугле ничего не нашел

> Post.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $guarded = false;
}
```

> PostController.php

```
public function create()
{

    $postsArr = [
        [
            'title' => 'DOTA 2',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'likes' => 228,
            'is_published' => 1
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Програмирование',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'likes' => 228,
            'is_published' => 1
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Семья',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'likes' => 228,
            'is_published' => 1
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Спорт',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'likes' => 228,
            'is_published' => 1
        ],
    ];

    foreach ($postsArr as $item) {
        dump($item);
        Post::create($item);
    }

    dd('created');
}
```

Comment: На кой черт Вы их создаете посредством перехода на страницу? Есть же [Database: Seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/seeding)

Comment: Так делает автор плейлиста на ютубе, я пока что еще учусь, и все таки хотелось бы узнать, почему оно создается 2 раза))

Comment: Понятия не имею, но я не думаю что это связано конкретно с SoftDeletes